# String interpolation in form inputs

Tags: ruby

In Rails, I'm trying to create video uploader forms for multiple video types.

I ended with code like this:

```
= semantic_form_for element, url: form_url, method: form_method, remote: true do |f|
  // there will be some form should return once
  - ['webm', 'mp4', 'ogv'].each do |ext|
    .video-item-uploader
      = f.input :"#{ext}", hint: [ f.object."#{ext}"? ? "#{I18n.t('uploaded')}" : '' ].join.html_safe
      = f.input :"#{ext + '_cache'}", as: :hidden

      = f.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: "#{I18n.t('do_delete')}"
```

With code like that, I got syntax errors. It works if I replace `"#{ext}"` with any text (without quotes) from array.

Is there any possibility to insert a variable inside a form input like that?

Comment: String interpolation is a term to use when you want to insert code evaluations inside a string. Your objective here does not seem to be that, and your wording is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= semantic_form_for element, url: form_url, method: form_method, remote: true do |f|
  // there will be some form should return once
  - %w(webm mp4 ogv).each do |ext|
    .video-item-uploader
      = f.input :"#{ext}", hint: [ f.object.send("#{ext}?")? ? "#{I18n.t('uploaded')}" : '' ].join.html_safe
      = f.input :"#{ext + '_cache'}", as: :hidden

      = f.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: "#{I18n.t('do_delete')}"
```

try this

Comment: all works except of f.object.send(ext)? - this code breaks all form. I tried use f.object.send("#{ext}")? - didn't help at all

Comment: edit it to f.object.send("#{ext}?") - it worked :) and after that i will accept your answer. Thank you!